# QFileInfo::fileName() does not work properly on different OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt5

I'm running Qt5 on Mac,

```
QFileInfo fi ("c:\\aaa\\bbb.txt");
qDebug () << fi.fileName();
```

I was expecting `bbb.txt` but the full path is returned instead.

That's weird, anyone know why? My guess it that `Mac paths` works on Mac Platform, and `Windows Paths` works on Windows Platform

Comment: ***Mac paths works on Mac Platform, and Windows Paths works on Windows Platform*** Yes, / is the path separator on mac  not \ so the whole thing looks like a filename. Also c: is meaningless.

Comment: @drescherjm Can I set a custom QDir::separator() on this?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can not set that. If you need to manipulate windows paths on a mac you may have to do a QString replace of `\\` with '/' then replace back after you are done.

Comment: You could use the [QDir::separator()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#separator), and [QDir::cleanPath( ... )](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#cleanPath) functions to get the desired path on all OS.